# Android: unexplained 'process died' issue

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Every time i try to launch my program, based on libgdx, on android emulator (Oracle VM VirtualBox), it dies.
Android v4.4.4
But on real devices it works great.

This happen's when i try to launch my program:

```
07-05 15:07:46.722 system_process I: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.mygdx.game.android/.AndroidLauncher} from pid 1551
07-05 15:07:46.726 system_process W: Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (187x140) to layer 21020
07-05 15:07:46.740 system_process I: Start proc com.mygdx.game.android for activity com.mygdx.game.android/.AndroidLauncher: pid=29928 uid=10067 gids={50067, 3003, 1028, 1015, 1023}
07-05 15:07:46.761 system_process W: Permission Denial: broadcasting Intent { act=com.android.launcher3.action.LAUNCH flg=0x10 (has extras) } from com.cyanogenmod.trebuchet (pid=1551, uid=10019) requires com.google.android.launcher.permission.RECEIVE_LAUNCH_BROADCASTS due to receiver com.google.android.gms/.icing.proxy.ApplicationLauncherReceiver
07-05 15:07:46.761 system_process W: Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=com.android.launcher3.action.LAUNCH flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.icing.proxy.ApplicationLauncherReceiver requires com.android.launcher3.permission.RECEIVE_LAUNCH_BROADCASTS due to sender com.cyanogenmod.trebuchet (uid 10019)
07-05 15:07:46.762 system_process W: Permission Denial: broadcasting Intent { act=com.android.launcher3.action.LAUNCH flg=0x10 (has extras) } from com.cyanogenmod.trebuchet (pid=1551, uid=10019) requires com.google.android.launcher.permission.RECEIVE_LAUNCH_BROADCASTS due to receiver com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.apps.gsa.search.core.icingsync.ApplicationLaunchReceiver
07-05 15:07:46.762 system_process W: Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=com.android.launcher3.action.LAUNCH flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.apps.gsa.search.core.icingsync.ApplicationLaunchReceiver requires com.android.launcher3.permission.RECEIVE_LAUNCH_BROADCASTS due to sender com.cyanogenmod.trebuchet (uid 10019)
07-05 15:07:46.830 system_process I: Process com.mygdx.game.android (pid 29928) has died.
07-05 15:07:46.841 system_process I: Start proc com.mygdx.game.android for activity com.mygdx.game.android/.AndroidLauncher: pid=29943 uid=10067 gids={50067, 3003, 1028, 1015, 1023}
07-05 15:07:46.882 system_process I: Process com.mygdx.game.android (pid 29943) has died.
07-05 15:07:46.914 system_process I: Start proc com.mygdx.game.android for activity com.mygdx.game.android/.AndroidLauncher: pid=29958 uid=10067 gids={50067, 3003, 1028, 1015, 1023}
07-05 15:07:46.954 system_process I: Process com.mygdx.game.android (pid 29958) has died.
07-05 15:07:46.954 system_process W: Force removing ActivityRecord{21c2b398 u0 com.mygdx.game.android/.AndroidLauncher t12}: app died, no saved state
07-05 15:07:46.982 system_process W: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@21b26990 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@21a67918
```

Can someone help?